# Is there a way to compare if both the username and password are valid pairs inside of dict login_info?

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know if there's some type of functionality that will compare the user and password are inside of the dict login_info.

I tried a for loop, but that went pretty downhill.

```
def login_account():
    user_guess = input('Type your username:  ')
    pass_guess = input('Type your password:  ')
    if user_guess not in login_info:
        print('That user does not exist')
    elif ## comparison if user and password are inside of login_info



login_info = {"Username": "Password"}
```

I want the elif to be able to compare the user and password to check if it's inside of login_info. If there's a way to do that. Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Invert the logic to handle the successful case first.

```
def login_account():
    user_guess = input('Type your username:  ')
    pass_guess = input('Type your password:  ')
    if user_guess in login_info and login_info[user_guess] == pass_guess:
        print('Successful login')
    elif user_guess in login_info:
        print('Wrong password')
    else:
        print('Unknown user')
```